# Deepspeech NodeJs Module_Not_Found Err

Tags: node.js, mozilla-deepspeech

Cannot Run the following code, everything I try to run it I run it into the issue of

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
```

Is this issue with me using Windows, or is it that my packages aren't installed correctly because I installed all the necessary ones and I still get the error.
Following Code

```
const DeepSpeech = require('deepspeech');
const Fs = require('fs');
const Sox = require('sox-stream');
const MemoryStream = require('memory-stream');
const Duplex = require('stream').Duplex;
const Wav = require('node-wav');

let modelPath = './models/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm';

let model = new DeepSpeech.Model(modelPath);

let desiredSampleRate = model.sampleRate();

let scorerPath = './models/deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer';

model.enableExternalScorer(scorerPath);

let audioFile = process.argv[2] || 'TestAudio.wav';

if (!Fs.existsSync(audioFile)) {
    console.log('file missing:', audioFile);
    process.exit();
}

const buffer = Fs.readFileSync(audioFile);
const result = Wav.decode(buffer);

if (result.sampleRate < desiredSampleRate) {
    console.error('Warning: original sample rate (' + result.sampleRate + ') is lower than ' + desiredSampleRate + 'Hz. Up-sampling might produce erratic speech recognition.');
}

function bufferToStream(buffer) {
    let stream = new Duplex();
    stream.push(buffer);
    stream.push(null);
    return stream;
}

let audioStream = new MemoryStream();
bufferToStream(buffer).
pipe(Sox({
    global: {
        'no-dither': true,
    },
    output: {
        bits: 16,
        rate: desiredSampleRate,
        channels: 1,
        encoding: 'signed-integer',
        endian: 'little',
        compression: 0.0,
        type: 'raw'
    }
})).
pipe(audioStream);

audioStream.on('finish', () => {
    let audioBuffer = audioStream.toBuffer();
    
    const audioLength = (audioBuffer.length / 2) * (1 / desiredSampleRate);
    console.log('audio length', audioLength);
    
    let result = model.stt(audioBuffer);
    
    console.log('result:', result);
});
```

Packages

```
"dependencies": {
    "cjs": "^0.0.11",
    "deepspeech": "^0.9.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "memory-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "node-wav": "^0.0.2",
    "sox-stream": "^2.0.6",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
```

Running on Windows 11 x64.

Tryed clearing cache, updating packages, installing in a new project.